# Some users get a NullReferenceException but I can't find the cause (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I have an application on which users from my company can register new opportunities.
It worked great, but now suddenly **some users only** are experciencing problems when posting the form and get a NullReferenceException error

Here is the detailed error from my logs:

> fail:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYJ3M.png)
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at AspNetCore.Views_Tender_Create.<>c__DisplayClass64_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> in Create.cshtml:line 107
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(Boolean
> useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
> context, TagHelperOutput output)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.g__Awaited|0_0(Task
> task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32
> count)
> at AspNetCore.Views_Tender_Create.ExecuteAsync() in Create.cshtml:line
> 6
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData,
> ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1
> statusCode)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, ViewResult result)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
> middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

When I look at line 107 in Create.cshtml, I see this:
[image]

Looks fine too me, and it's working for most of the users.

So due to the fact that only some users are experiencing problems (2 colleagues from Luxemburg) I need to look somewhere else.

I'm using Windows Authentication for my project and it works fine. Also the users from Luxemburg are able to open the application.

When creating a new opportunity, I also get user data from Windows:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);

var ownerUserName = "onbekend";
var ownerFirstName = "onbekend";
var ownerLastName = "onbekend";
var ownerEmail = "onbekend";
var ownerFullName = "onbekend";

if (user != null)
{
ownerUserName = user.Name; 
ownerFirstName = user.GivenName;
ownerLastName = user.Surname;
ownerEmail = user.EmailAddress;
ownerFullName = user.DisplayName;
}
```

So I thought that might be the problem, but it's not. I made a testing page and the userdata is found correctly from the ActiveDirectory.

I'm googling for days now, trying to find an answer.

I just don't know what else to try...

Comment: Are the users that are having this problem using a different language than other users? This could cause some errors. It also sounds like they authenticate in a different way, but it looks like you tested it - that a good idea (both authentication and the ldap lookup)

Comment: They do speak a different language (French) than most other users (Dutch), but the application is in English. I did ask them to test it with different browsers too, and to make sure that the Google Translate function was disabled. Same result.

I also tried filling out the form myself with exactly the same data as those users... and that works perfectly. So also entering French letters & symbols in the form isn't the issue.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to find out WHAT exactly is NULL with these users. I got the error message and in my opinion it tells me nothing on where to deepdive. I also can't debug because when I try it, I don't get an error.

Comment: Please tell me what code to share, I really need help. I can't share the entire application due to company policy

Comment: Really not sure. I think you're on the right path. I'd try changing my browser language (there's a setting that changes it for website:https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities . I don't know about Core MVC, but .NET Framework MVC used that header to change the default locale for all operations (still, I wouldn't expect null exception)

Comment: And, I'd try to get the test login page to be as close as possible to the real thing, and if possible try to debug with a remote connection.

Comment: I'll try both advices but I don't think it will help. How can I debug with a remote connection? Obviously the "error-users" don't have Visual studio installed. Is there a way to simulate their experience? I use Windows Authentication, so I can't pretend to e another user on my pc/laptop.

Comment: depending on how easy it is, you might be able to get a vm on the same location, with a dedicated user.

Comment: For now...no success :-(

I'm not able to reproduce the error myself, so it's very hard to debug.

I discussed it with a colleague and he advised me to add (a lot of) try/catch pieces in my code, with custom error messages.

So I did...in my controller and my model. Same error, same stack trace.

So generally the error must happen in the razor view:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at AspNetCore.Views_Tender_Create.<>c__DisplayClass64_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in Create.cshtml:line 107 -

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that somehow my entire Viewmodel becomes NULL. Maybe I made a coding mistake, which appears to go well for 99% of the users, and wrong for 1%. 

In that case another option is to find the coding mistake rather than to find out why user A is getting an error and user B isn't.